# How to call method in activity from service in seperate process?

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I know how to call methods in service through aidl interface from activity. But how to call method in activity from service which is running in seperate process, without broadcast receiver ?

Is there any way i can call methods in my activity through same aidl interface or other java interface ?

Code:

```
//aidl interface
interface IRemoteServiceCallback {

    void valueChanged();
}

//starting service in activity
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(BackgroundService.class.getName());
serviceIntent.setPackage("com.example.service2");
startService(serviceIntent);
bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


//aidl stub implementation in activity
private IRemoteServiceCallback mCallback = new IRemoteServiceCallback.Stub() {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged() {

        System.out.println("Callback method called");
    }
};

//service connection in activity
BackgroundService mService = null;
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

        System.out.println("Callback service connected");
        try {

            mService.registerCallback(mCallback);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Service2-CallbackService-Connecting:", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {

        if (mService != null) {
            try {
                mService.unregisterCallback(mCallback);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Service2-CallbackService:", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
};

// registering callbacks in service
public void registerCallback(IRemoteServiceCallback mCallback) {

    System.out.println("Callback registers...");
    this.mCallback = mCallback;
}

public void unregisterCallback(IRemoteServiceCallback mCallback2) {

    this.mCallback = null;
}

//calling method
mCallback.valueChanged();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

You can use callbacks through interfaces registered through service connection.

```
/** 
     * This implementation is used to receive callbacks from the remote 
     * service. 
     */ 
    private IRemoteServiceCallback mCallback = new IRemoteServiceCallback.Stub() {
        /** 
         * This is called by the remote service regularly to tell us about 
         * new values.  Note that IPC calls are dispatched through a thread 
         * pool running in each process, so the code executing here will 
         * NOT be running in our main thread like most other things -- so, 
         * to update the UI, we need to use a Handler to hop over there. 
         */ 
        public void valueChanged(int value) {
            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(BUMP_MSG, value, 0));
        } 
    }; 

    private static final int BUMP_MSG = 1;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() { 
        @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
            switch (msg.what) { 
                case BUMP_MSG: 
                    mCallbackText.setText("Received from service: " + msg.arg1); 
                    break; 
                default: 
                    super.handleMessage(msg); 
            } 
        } 

    };
```

// for registering the callbacks from activity

```
 private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                    IBinder service) {
                // This is called when the connection with the service has been 
                // established, giving us the service object we can use to 
                // interact with the service.  We are communicating with our 
                // service through an IDL interface, so get a client-side 
                // representation of that from the raw service object. 
                ....

                // We want to monitor the service for as long as we are 
                // connected to it. 
                try { 
                    mService.registerCallback(mCallback);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // In this case the service has crashed before we could even 
                    // do anything with it; we can count on soon being 
                    // disconnected (and then reconnected if it can be restarted) 
                    // so there is no need to do anything here. 
                } 
            } 

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
                // This is called when the connection with the service has been 
                // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed. 
               ...
                 if (mService != null) {
                    try { 
                        mService.unregisterCallback(mCallback);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        // There is nothing special we need to do if the service 
                        // has crashed. 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        };
```

> You need to create registerCallback and unregisterCallback in service,
>   and call the interface when required
>   Blockquote

//Code snippet from Service

```
IRemoteServiceCallback mCallback;
    public void registerCallback(IRemoteServiceCallback callback) {
        this.mCallback = callback;
    }

    public void unregisterCallback() {
        this.mCallback = null;
    }
    .
    .
    private void updateActivity() {
        if(mCallback != null) {
            **mCallback.valueChanged(10);**
        }
    }
```

Comment: They said about callback stub implementation in activity. But they didn't said anything about calling this stub-method from service.

Comment: Yes. This is activity part. What about service part ? How to call this from service ?

Comment: What to do in registerCallback() and unregisterCallback() in service ?

Comment: i'm getting null pointer exception: 04-15 16:29:09.117: E/BackgroundService-processPacket:(1109): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 
'void com.example.service2.IRemoteServiceCallback.valueChanged()' 
on a null object reference

Comment: I think i have answered your initial question "another way to communicate than Broadcasts"... You need to post the entire code for me to look into the problem, but accept this answer.

Comment: Ok. I got this. We need aidl stub implementation in both service and activity. registerCallback() and unregisterCallback() need to be define in aidl interface and implement in these stubs. Then we can pass mCallback to Service-Stub-registerCallback(). And then service can callback methods in activity with this mCallbcak.